# LWC test class failing

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I have this apex wire method in an LWC Component

```js
@wire(getCountriesData, { proposalId: '$proposalId' })
   countriesData(result) {
    this.wiredCountriesData = result;
    if (result.data)
    {
      this.countriesDataArray =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data));
    
      this.countriesDataArray.sort((a, b) => {
              return (a.sequenceNumber == undefined) - (b.sequenceNumber == undefined) 
          || +(a.sequenceNumber > b.sequenceNumber) 
          || -(a.sequenceNumber < b.sequenceNumber);
      })
      this.showSpinner = false;
    } else if (result.error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result.error));
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a test class for the same

```js
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import ManageCountries from 'c/ManageCountries';
import { registerLdsTestWireAdapter, registerApexTestWireAdapter } 
         from '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest';
import getCountriesData 
         from '@salesforce/apex/ManageCountriesController.getCountriesData';    
// Mock realistic data
const mockGetCountriesData = require('./data/getCountriesData.json');    
const getCountriesAdapter = registerApexTestWireAdapter(getCountriesData);
    
describe('c-manage-countries', () => {    
   afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a 
        // single file so reset the DOM
      while (document.body.firstChild) {
                document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
      }
   });
    
   it('wireMthodTest1', () => {
      const element = createElement('c-manage-countries', {is: ManageCountries});
      element.proposalId = 'a3l1x0000004b7NAAQ';
      document.body.appendChild(element);
    
      getCountriesAdapter.emit(mockGetCountriesData);
    
      return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                    // will write assert statements here.
                })
        });
    });
```

I keep getting the below error

[image]

```json
getCountriesData.JSON{
  "data": [
        {
          "ambComboInboundCourier": "Marken",
          "batchSize": 104,
          "countryId": "a6H1x00000095GSEAY",
          "countryName": "Albania (Tier 1)",
          "regionName": "EMEA",
          "selectedCountry": true,
          "sequenceNumber": 11,
        },
        {
          "ambComboInboundCourier": "Marken",
          "batchSize": 104,
          "countryId": "a6H1x00000095JeEAI",
          "countryName": "Argentina (Tier 1)",
          "regionName": "Americas",
          "selectedCountry": true,
          "sequenceNumber": 1,
        },
  ]
}
```

could someone please suggest what am I missing here.

Comment: Could you check or post the value defined in the file `getCountriesData.json`? I hope you have formatted the values based on sample snapshot of data provided REST client that accesses the UI API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_overview.htm)?

Comment: Any error in the mock data format could possibly not return the required data & type leading to unrecognized sort function. BTW, why do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data))` instead of simply using `result.data`?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated my question with what I have in getCountries.json and JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data)) for deep clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deep cloning, you can use the ES6 rest parameter syntax in LWC. Something like below

```
this.countriesDataArray = {...result.data};
```

However, the jest test failure could be due to the way you have the data in your JSON file.

Try using the below in the JSON

```
[
 {
  "ambComboInboundCourier": "Marken",
  "batchSize": 104,
  "countryId": "a6H1x00000095GSEAY",
  "countryName": "Albania (Tier 1)",
  "regionName": "EMEA",
  "selectedCountry": true,
  "sequenceNumber": 11,
 },
 {
  "ambComboInboundCourier": "Marken",
  "batchSize": 104,
  "countryId": "a6H1x00000095JeEAI",
  "countryName": "Argentina (Tier 1)",
  "regionName": "Americas",
  "selectedCountry": true,
  "sequenceNumber": 1,
 }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried without data also, but the same didn't work and this.countriesDataArray = {...result.data}; doesn't do deep clone.

Comment: sorry my bad issue fixed now the error is different, will solve the new one, thank you for your help.